# Firebase - query a property of an object with an specific and non-specific value

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running a basic query to a small DB that is structured as follow:

- carMake:
- carModel:
- carColor:

Let's say first 2 fields have specific information:

- carMake: "Ford"
- carModel: "Mustang"

But for the third field, I can query all values with the specific color: red, blue etc. The question I have is how can I query the third field using:

- carColor: "All Colors"

If "All Colors" is not a specific value? I've used: .whereField(CAR_COLOR, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo or arrayContains or arrayContainsAny, etc) and it doesn't work. I get no results. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If you want it to return everything regardless of what color is in that field, why use a `whereField` query at all?

Comment: The carColor field is to give an option to the end user if they want to filter to a specific color (red, blue, etc) or if they want to see everything regardless of the color they can use "All Colors"

Comment: Okay. So, if they choose "all colors" then I'm struggling to see why you would use `whereField` on `carColor` at all in that instance.

Comment: "All Colors" is not assigned to any carColor object. I use whereField so the user can filter to a specific color. Let me ask you this then, is it possible to bypass the carColor field if in the query I'm selecting "All Colors"? but if the query has a specific color "Red", don't bypass and run it?

Comment: Most simply, you could just use `if { } else { }` to run different queries. But, if you want to use the same query chain, I've added an answer below that would allow one to use a conditional `whereField` query. You would want to pass `false` for `useCondition` in the event that you *did not* want to run the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments discussion, it sounds like you want to be able to include `whereField` in your query chain, but not actually execute it if certain conditions are true/false.

I suggest adding an extension to `Query`:

```
extension Query {
    func whereField(useCondition: Bool, _ field: String, arrayContains: String) -> Query {
        if useCondition {
            return self.whereField(field, arrayContains: arrayContains)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
db.collection("car").whereField(useCondition: !allColors, "carColor", arrayContains: searchedColor)
```

Note that you may have to adjust this to fit the variety of `whereField` that you need.